# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: jquery, php, mysql, javascript

Здравствуйте, есть проблема, написал подгрузку контента при помощи скроллинга, вот код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var num = 12;
   var inProcess = false;
   $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() && !inProcess)
      {
         $.ajax({
            url: "/load.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: {"num" : num},
            beforeSend: function() {
               inProcess = true;
            }

            }).done(function(data) {
               content = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
               if (content.status == "success")
               {
                  data = content.data;
                  if (data.length > 0)
                  {
                     $.each(content.data, function(index, item){
                        $(".row-fluid").append('<div class="col-lg-3"><div class = "item"><div class = "poster"><img src="/upload/posters/'+item.url+'"></div><div class="img-hover" onclick="myfunct('+item.id+')"><img src="/template/img/img-prev.png" height="70" width="70"></div><div class = "detals"><h3><a href = "'+item.id+'">'+item.name+'</a></h3></div></div></div>');
                     });
                     inProcess = false;
                     num+=12;
                  }
               } else {
                  alert('no');
               }
            });

      }else {

      }
   });
});
```

когда обновляю страницу проблем нет, пару раз спущусь полностью вниз, проблем не возникает, но как только информация из бд пропадает, вот что говорит консоль:
[image]

Comment: Проблема может быть в HTML-строке, которую вы вычисляете. (Вы не экранируете спецсимволы, кстати!) Попробуйте подсмотреть аргумент `$(".row-fluid").append()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется ошибка все в том же ответе с сервера...
Функция jQuery.parseJSON ожидает что строка начинается с '{', а у Вас судя по всему начинается с '<'